# Adding a decrement field to a csv file

Tags: text-processing, awk, osx

I have a CSV file with something like

```
10;12;33;44;55;66;77;88
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
110;112;133;144;155;616;771;818
...etc
```

Every line has eight numbers separated by `;`.

I need to add a new field at the beginning of each line, starting with 1184 and going down, so the final file will be

```
1184;10;12;33;44;55;66;77;88
1183;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
1182;110;112;133;144;155;616;771;818
... etc
```

How may I do that with `awk` or something that works on macOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN { n = 1184 } { printf("%d;%s\n", n--, $0) }' infile >outfile
```

Alternatively, if you want to set `n` on the command line:

```
awk -v n=1184 '{ printf("%d;%s\n", n--, $0) }' infile >outfile
```

Alternatively, using `print` instead of `printf`:

```
awk -v n=1184 '{ print n-- ";" $0 }' infile >outfile
```

Alternatively, letting `awk` insert the field delimiter between the new field and the rest of the line:

```
awk -v n=1184 -v OFS=';' '{ print n--, $0 }' infile >outfile
```

Alternatively, modify the first `;`-delimited field only and then print the record:

```
awk -F ';' -v n=1184 -v OFS=';' '{ $1 = n-- OFS $1; print }' infile >outfile
```

This would prefix each existing line with the number stored in the variable `n` and at the same time decrement that variable.  The existing data on the line would be passed on unmodified.

The output is written to `outfile` and given the example data in the question, this would look like

```
1184;10;12;33;44;55;66;77;88
1183;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
1182;110;112;133;144;155;616;771;818
```

The two filenames `infile` and `outfile` need to be different, or you will end up emptying your input data file and loosing it.

Comment: can you explain what the syntaxes do?

Comment: @SpaceDog Which variation are you unsure about?  The `printf()` function works as in any other programming language that it's available in, and `print` prints a number of fields, separated by the value of `OFS`.  The third example concatenates the number, the `;` and the rest of the line as a single field (as far as `awk` is concerned), the fourth example shows how to output two distinct fields (`awk` puts the value of `OFS` in-between them).  The visible effect of all of them is identical.